# How to avoid theft of potentially patentable IP when trying to obtain a Ph.D?

Tags: publications, phd, patents

When I was fresh out of college, I worked with someone who had their Ph.D who I'll call **X**.  They told me that they had lunch with a person from Facebook who had told them about a Novel Algorithm Facebook had created.  **X** decided to do a patent search on this algorithm, and it did not exist. Therefore, **X** decided to patent it himself as a System and Method.

My researched solution to a problem could potentially be worth millions of dollars.  I don't mean to sound braggadocious or grandiose, but I have experience in the industry, and I'm aware of how potentially valuable it could be.  I was thinking about doing a Ph.D on it. How do I prevent professors such as **X** from patenting my solution, or presenting it as their own idea in a publication? Since my solution could potentially be worth so much money, should I just patent it myself? The only caveat is that it is super expensive to do that.  Should I apply for a grant on grant.gov?  Should I write a manuscript in arXiv.org?  Should I try to write a business plan and try to get funding?

Comment: What is a patent troll?

Comment: I think the usage here isn't the standard one. Patent trolls normally buy up existing patents and then sue people for infringement on shaky (or not shaky) grounds. I think the intention here is to imply someone stealing the idea and patenting it themselves.

Comment: If you did a PhD on the topic, in many institutions that would give them a claim on whatever you produce (sometimes giving you only minority royalties even if sold), whether you try to patent it or have them patent it. Policy/agreements vary by institution. Ultimately the strategy you should take for monetizing or defending intellectual property will be beyond the scope of this stack, as it requires a deep familiarity with your local laws, market for IP in that industry, etc. Many Universities have IP development/grant programs, so you might consider checking what they offer. YMMV

Comment: If you publish it on arXiv or disclose it in a business plan, you're just making your idea public. That's fine if your goal is to be famously recognized as the inventor, but not if you want to be the first to commercialize it. It might depend on the jurisdiction but usually a patent can only be granted for an idea which hasn't been published before (but IANAL).

Comment: "Theft of intellectual property" would be a more accurate label, not "trolling", etc.

Comment: The story told sound completely implausible to me. If Facebook is far enough along development of something patentable that a description over lunch would allow someone to scoop it, then they would have already patented it.

Comment: If X is patenting something that someone from Facebook told them at lunch has been invented at Facebook, then either 1. the blabbermouth, 2. the person that failed to patent it (if so) or 3. prof X are in for a very big surprise, possibly all three. I am surprised that such information about a vulnerable invention would go out without an NDA. OP may want to inform themselves about the IP policy of their academic institution. It is probably not as powerful as FB, but will still be interested in IP not getting violated.

Comment: In the US, provisional patents last a year and are secret. Pending patents can take years after that to become searchable. The friend really had no idea if facebook submitted a patent on the idea already or not.

Comment: What's stopping you contacting patent lawyers and patenting your idea before doing the PhD?

Comment: Are your fears of getting it stolen rational? Have you asked yourself whether the invention is truly "worth millions of dollars" for the inventor (that is, not only market turnaround or the most common scenario, a big player keeping the benefits)? Are you aware that people tend to dismiss new ideas, and that probably you'll need to shovel any new idea down their throats?

Comment: @Quora Feans Yes, it is rational.  Any technology that can stop malware propagation is potentially worth a lot of money.

Comment: @GaryDrocella: inventors tend to overestimate the earning potential of their ideas, and to overestimate the share of earnings they will keep.

Comment: @Quora Feans I am aware that I could be overestimating it, but I could also be underestimating it.

Comment: @BryanKrause, sadly, that *is* one way that patents can work. Since 2011, substantially all countries implement a "[First to file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_to_file_and_first_to_invent)" system for awarding patents (that being the year the U.S. converted to that approach).  What the OP describes may not be *ethical*, but that does not impact the potential validity of the patent.

Comment: Do you even need to make the PoC first? I'm not a patent lawyer, but I am listed as the inventor of a patent (only a software patent - not a real one!), and I spoke to the patent lawyers who were drawing up the application on a couple of occasions: I sent them a written explanation of the algorithm and then talked them through it on a phone call. They did everything else. (In my case I was never going to be listed as patent holder, I don't agree with software patents anyway, and I don't think that it was ever granted in the end because it was something silly)

Comment: @Aaron F I read somewhere on the internet that you need to build a prototype first, but I am not sure of its validity.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Seems you are right, comment removed. They would still be potentially able to challenge the validity but it seems to be an uphill battle in particular if the conversation is not documented.

Answer (score 30):

Let me describe fairly typical practice at reputable US universities. When someone has a patentable idea, the university itself will take over the patent process, paying lawyers and fees. The university will probably be the patent holder of record, but will make arrangements with the actual creator(s) to share any income that results from exploiting the patent.

This can be good or bad, I suppose, but the good part is that the university covers the cost and also provides backup if anyone challenges the patent at any point. This can be very difficult for an individual to do on their own. The bad part is that the patent is probably in the university's name, though that may vary.  Another point is that the university may take it upon itself to find ways to monetize the patent if it is awarded. Again, this can be a large expense for an individual.

But one protection for you, a student with an idea, is that if the university is, indeed, reputable, it won't try to steal your idea or let a faculty member steal it.

But faculty at the (reputable) institutions that do a lot of patentable research normally require this (or a similar) process as part of the contract with the faculty member. Such agreements might also be necessary for a student to participate in such work. And there is usually an office, full of lawyers, dedicated to shepherding such work. So a further expectation is that the university is not only reputable, but also large enough to support that office.

And the sharing arrangement may be standardized or, possibly, negotiated, so long as costs can be expected to be covered.

The situation and the rules will also probably vary by a lot in other countries.

---

For completeness, I'll note that large companies doing important research also tend to have (and require) some similar arrangements with their own researchers.

Comment: The University of Cambridge is not a US university (but I would argue it *is* reputable).  They too have systems in place to protect IP developed during research, and a mechanism to develop it.

Comment: @MartinBonner, ha ha ha. Yes, I would agree that Cambridge is (a) not US and (b) reputable. I've been led to believe that UK has _many_ reputable universities, actually. ;-)

Comment: Well yes, but I only have direct knowledge of one.

Comment: Hi Dr. Buffy, would a top 10 school be considered reputable?

Answer (score 12):

About doing a PhD, before thinking about academics stealing your idea you might want to think about how you are going to publish papers (usually a requirement during the PhD) if you want to keep your idea secret. As far as I know you won't be able to publish anything before the patent is filed (*), and that could take a few years. It doesn't mean that it's impossible but it might be tricky.

The alternative to the [academic route described in Buffy's answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/133920/93566) is to create your own start-up first, then develop and patent your idea under the name of your company. This might take a few years and will cost a lot of money indeed. If you can make sure that your idea is viable and really worth millions of dollars, then it's still a sound investment.

The first step would be to consult with a good specialized lawyer who will advise you on how to proceed (for instance inform you about NDAs, you will probably need these). Again, it's worth the expense in order to avoid making mistakes which could easily ruin your business.

(*) [edit] I initially thought you can't publish until the patent is *granted*, but I'm told in the comments it's actually only until the patent is *filed*... That's a good illustration of why you need a lawyer ;)

Comment: I guess that details are more complicated, but my IANAL understanding is that you can publish anything you want once the patent application is FILED.

Comment: @HonzaBrabec Thank you, you're probably right. I edited my answer and added one more reason to ask a lawyer for advice!

Answer (score 7):

What you describe is closer to "scooping" than "patent trolling". But actually it's just theft.

If you truly believe your invention is valuable, then you can patent it yourself. You would need to find a reputable patent lawyer. And you can expect to pay thousands of dollars in fees. (Beware of disreputable patent lawyers.) Plus you will likely need the help of lawyers again to actually collect any money from your patent, as you must sue those who infringe on your patent, or at least threaten to do so.

If you just want credit for your invention, write a paper about it and stick it on arxiv or a similar repository. The arxiv timestamp clearly establishes precedence. That means no one else can subsequently patent the invention -- your work becomes prior art that invalidates any subsequent patent. Sharing your invention like this does not immediately prevent you from patenting it. However, there are time limits. I believe you need to submit a patent within one year of making it public.

Note that your employer may claim ownership of any intellectual property that you create. For example, most universities do this. On the positive side, this means they may pay for the patent. On the negative side, they may claim some or all of the money you get from it.

Comment: Keep in mind that doing this instantly makes it prior art in Europe. There's no delay.

Answer (score 4):

*I was thinking about doing a Ph.D. on it . . . "*

I think the first question is for yourself as a person. 
Which human environment do you prefer to work in ? The business environment or the academic environment ?
This is the essential question here as people in these two sectors relate and associate in completely different ways.

If you have the urge to impart and receive knowledge freely, are comfortable in situations of psychological trust with young people and not too worldly when it comes to money, maybe a Ph.D. **with the right supervisor** is a valid consideration. If you go this route, don't expect to be rich. Staff at colleges sometimes make millions from their work but no student does - unless the insights are kept secret and developed later off-campus.

But don't go into a Ph.D. just to experiment/develop an idea you want to commercialize. Campus life - and the kind of people there, good and bad - will find you out, drain your confidence and leave you feeling socially isolated. For the rapport, team-work, thrilling intensity and chillouts - these are the preserve of the private sector where the necessity of making a living fuse people's mind together. Patent trollers are a natural hazard here but you'll have support from your own company and many patent attorneys will undertake protection work on the understanding of later payment after patents are granted.

Comment: ''Campus life - and the kind of people there, good and bad - will find you out, drain your confidence and leave you feeling socially isolated.''  Unfortunately true.

Comment: This answer deserves to be accepted.

Comment: "Campus life - and the kind of people there, good and bad - will find you out, drain your confidence and leave you feeling socially isolated." Are you saying that this would happen if people discovered I was trying to commercialize what I was researching there?

Comment: Basically, you want the university to fund your secret startup company for a few years, in exchange for pretending to be an academic researcher. Most organizations (and the people in them) don't like being on the wrong end what looks like a financial scam, even if it's not actually illegal.

Comment: _For the rapport, team-work, thrilling intensity and chillouts - these are the preserve of the private sector_ — Objection! There are lots of supportive and nurturing academic environments, and lots of toxic non-academic environments.  I'm sorry your academic experience was so negative, but that's _not_ universal.

Comment: "these are the preserve of the private sector where the necessity of making a living fuse people's mind together" - I have spent a little time (a long while ago) in the private sector, I have several friends who have either recently spent time in the private sector or left academia for the private sector some year ago, and the claim I have quoted above is, to put it mildly, hyperbolic and far from guaranteed

Comment: @Gary Drocella No, I'm not saying that individual staff or fellow PhDs would shun you because of your own plans. I'm saying that unless you are congenial to the human environment you'll be in for the duration of your doctorate,  your confidence - professional and personal - will be continually worn down. You won't simply be able to use the library, labs, etc of a postgraduate school for years and remain your own essential self.

Comment: @JeffE and Yemon Choi: Sure there are mad working environments in the private sector. People hoping to make some money or do 'cutting-edge research' encounter these to their horror. And victims of these employers would look hard at the workplace human environment after their experience. JeffE says there are *many* nurturing academic environments. I say that there are *few* - based on time at 6 of them in 2 countries. More a case of Exception! rather than Objection! You should appreciate finding one, JeffE. Let no one with a gift for synthesizing others' work get tenure or he'll wreck it all.

Comment: @Trunk I insist that there are many, based on time spent at dozens of them, mostly in the US, but in at least eight different countries, over a span of almost 30 years.

Comment: @JeffE  *... based on time spent at dozens of them... in at least 8 different countries.* You should do a Michael Porteresque book on how healthy university departments efficiently excrete - without creating a media stink - those inadequate faculty who mannerized, socialised and synthesized their way to tenure. But *Dump The Deadwood: A Strategy For Competitive Advantage In Academia* would get some very critical reviews from real educators. Seriously, at Berkeley didn't any law school girl whisper anything sad to you during a slowdance about that useless Professor Bundy?

Comment: @Trunk I am not claiming that there are no toxic academic environments.  And after years spent on this forum, I'm not even claiming that _most_ academic environments are healthy, despite that being true of the academic environments I've been in.  **Many ≠ most**.  But I've seen zero evidence that industry is inherently more supportive than academia—see any number of horror stories at Workplace.

Comment: Okay. We're drifting off course here a bit. I just wanted to get @Gary Drocella straight on the human environment thing as it's so important and so totally understated by most people. It makes a *colossal* effect on creative performance - and creating is where a good researcher should be. Sure, toxic work environments exist in all arenas, public or private sector, the arts, entertainment - even the charities and voluntary organizations. Each of us have to choose the arena where we can handle the crackpots around us and maybe protect others stuck there till they get a more congenial job.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: Sorry, misread question. Salvaging what I can of it.**

It's best not to get too carried away with the commercial potential of new ideas. It's one thing to come up with something, but something else entirely to connect that to a customer who will pay more than it cost you to develop it. And then there's the possibility that Facebook and others already know about it and are treating it as a [Trade Secret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trade_secret). In the latter case your patent may not be worth much at all and could potentially be overturned in court.

I'd suggest thinking carefully about what your business plan would be, who your potential customers are, and how your product would be used by them. Would they license your IP? Would you work as a consultant to implement it on their systems? If the idea is just to "make millions" simply positioning yourself as a gifted developer who independently discovered **X** could be enough to get your foot in the door of some very high-paying firms. Or to put it another way, you may be worth a good deal more than your patent.

For Universities, policies will vary from place to place so you should consider consulting them directly. In Australia students generally are not required to give up their IP, but can voluntarily do so in return for some royalties and the University footing the bill for patent applications and legal protection of said patent. You'll need to assess for yourself whether the trade-off is worthwhile.

And finally, if you're worried about being scooped by Prof X then I'd strongly advise #1 not telling him and #2 documenting the development of your idea in a way that would be independently verifiable in court if necessary.

Comment: "if you're worried about being scooped by Prof X" If Professor X wants to scoop you, you're screwed; he's psychic.

Comment: We weren't working at Facebook at the time, and this all occurred sometime in 2013. I don't think that Facebook would have any idea about my invention.  It's kind of outside of their scope.  I do fear that some of the big dogs such as McAfee would come after me, though.  I haven't worked there, but my invention could seriously undermine the necessity of their product.

Comment: Your solution would need to be implemented, no? Sounds like plenty of work for McAfee and their peers. I'd imagine large companies like that would rather buy you out and make you sign an NDA rather than try and steal your technology. Sure, they *could* steal it, but a couple of million is probably money well spent if it stops you sharing the product with their competitors.

In any case, I think you're underestimating how much work it would be for every individual and company on earth to implement your technology. You're better off getting 1% of $1,000,000,000 than 100% of $0.

Answer (score 0):

Its important to note what a university's position on IP is. At my university, all students sign the university's PI policy. That policy states that students cannot be named as inventors on patents that arise out of university supported research, only their supervisors can. By doing a PhD on your idea, you might be guaranteeing that you cannot patent the idea.